# Leak in wall behind push/pull bathtub faucet

Tags: plumbing, leak, plumbing-fixture, leaks

Have a push/pull faucet for our upstairs bathtub/shower, and it recently started leaking behind the shower wall and onto the ceiling below.

It appears to only leak when the faucet isn't pushed completely closed. Any idea how I can fix this? See images below.

[image][image]

Comment: That is a Moen valve. All parts are replaceable/repairable but you need to give us more information.

it is apparent from your pictures that you have access to the rear of the unit. Let it leak while you are inspecting from there, to pinpoint the location/area of the leak. If it is coming from above the valve assembly then you can pretty much assume that the pipe path to the shower head is compromised (could be the connection where the shower arm connects to the "in-wall piping" or it could be the piping that runs from the valve assembly up to the shower arm/head assembly).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is leaking around that main escutcheon. Re-caulk around this escutcheon.  leave a weep hole at the bottom.